# How to install Zend Framework 2 on ubuntu?

Tags: apache2, php, mysql, xampp, zendframework

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to install Zendframework 2 on Ubuntu 14.04, and also a tutorial teaching how to use ZendFramework 2. Could someone help me?

If it is useful to know, I'm with XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4, Apache/2.4.7, and MySql 5.6.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download directly the lib by pulling the git repository:

https://github.com/zendframework/zf2

PS: Don't download from the master branch, choose a tag.

Or, if you know how to use composer, a PHP package manager, thats an option too.

You could learn by reading the guides in the official web site:
http://framework.zend.com/learn/

More download options:
http://framework.zend.com/downloads

A personal note: Zend is a complex framework if it is yours first experience using a MVC framework. I recommend you to try Cake or Laravel(Ruby on Rails style) if it is your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I already knew that Zend is more advanced, I know CodeIgniter, which is for beginners but I find it interesting to know the zend, because I see the job ads requiring ZendFramework!

Comment: When I tried to install via composer, it tried to install a dependency `phpunit/phpunit 5.4.2` which failed as it needed `dom` php extension. Similarly, `zendframework/zend-ldap` needed `ldap` extension to be enabled. How do I install these extensions on ubuntu, and more importantly, why does a framework ask me to enable extensions even before I use them?